# What did Osaka mean by "floaties you get in your eyes"?

Tags: azumanga-daioh

What did Osaka mean by this 4-koma manga ?

[image]

Comment: Related on Biology.SE [What exactly are “floaters”](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17897/what-exactly-are-floaters) (check the duplicate for the answer. used my question because of the title using floaters)

Comment: OHHHH my... i kinda have seen those thing too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are called [floater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floater), you know the thing that look like worm and when you move your eyes they also move away (usually done by a kid or childish person, they're chasing the floater). They look like this

[image: Floater]

Comment: I love how the same image has been used in three answers (two of which on [biology.se])!